# How to display Swagger JSON file in my MEAN stack project using swagger-ui module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm new to NodeJS and AngularJS so I might be approaching this completely wrong but worth asking...

I'm trying to use the [swagger-ui Node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui) to display my API's documentation in a Swagger-ish style with interactivity.

I want to do this within my NodeJS app by passing in my own Swagger JSON file (hosted in `public/assets/my-swagger.json`).

I'm assuming I can do something like this:

```
angular.module('SwaggerCtrl', []).controller('SwaggerController', function($scope) {

    $scope.swagger = new function() {
        var swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
            url: '../../assets/my-swagger.json',
            dom_id: "swagger-ui-container"
        });

        swaggerUi.load();
    };

});
```

Which is taken from https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui#swaggerui.

And then in my `swagger.html` I would do something like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Swagger</h1>

    <p>{{ swagger }}</p>

    <div id="swagger-ui-container"></div>
</div>
```

However, when I go to http://localhost:8080/swagger, I get `ReferenceError: SwaggerUi is not defined` error message on my console.

I'm trying to figure out how to call the `swaggerUi.load()` so that it loads the `my-swagger.json` file when the user goes to http://localhost:8080/swagger.

I also looked at https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-middleware but it's loading the default Petstore API found in the `node_modules/swagger-ui/dist` directory.

Comment: There is an [angular implementation of swagger-ui](https://libraries.io/bower/angular-swagger-ui), have you seen it?

Comment: How do you use it? I can't find any documentation.

Comment: I'm using jquery, and get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this too and have used those two modules: swagger-jsdoc (it generates the swagger.json from comments in your node.js file and swagger-ui-express to display the information.

Look at the doc for the later, you might find the answer to your question.